# How to divide dates into static periods

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a date column, which i have to divide into **TWO** established groups **(GROUP A and GROUP B)** of 14 days interspersed indefinitely.

For example, between the dates '2021-04-09' and '2021-04-22' correspond to **Group A**, the dates between '2021-04-23' and '2021-05-06' correspond to **Group B**, the dates between '2021-05-07' and '2021-05-20' correspond to **Group A**, and so on.

I want to make an additional column, which calculates whether a certain date is in group A or group B.

```
CREATE TABLE dates (
  date DATE
);

INSERT INTO dates VALUES ('2021-04-20');
INSERT INTO dates VALUES ('2021-04-21');
INSERT INTO dates VALUES ('2021-04-22');
INSERT INTO dates VALUES ('2021-04-23');
INSERT INTO dates VALUES ('2021-04-24');
INSERT INTO dates VALUES ('2021-04-25');
```

Expected result:

| date | group |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-20 | GROUP A |
| 2021-04-21 | GROUP A |
| 2021-04-22 | GROUP A |
| 2021-04-23 | GROUP B |
| 2021-04-24 | GROUP B |
| 2021-04-25 | GROUP B |

Sorry that for the first time in a question I can not place an attempt. The best I could do is put all the dates statically. I don't even know if it can be done in a calculated way.

```
select date, 
CASE 
WHEN (date between '2021-04-20' and '2021-04-22') THEN 'GROUP A'
WHEN (date between '2021-04-23' and '2021-04-25') THEN 'GROUP B'
ELSE 'UNKNOWN' END as group
from dates
```

Comment: Is the fact that you start Group A on April 20 only for the example? Do you use calendar year to start Group A at all? My initial instinct was to use some combination of `ROUND(DATENAME(dy, Date) / 14, 0)` and converting that number to a letter, but that would assume Jan 1 to Jan 7 is Week 1/Group A. Not to mention, what happens after 26 weeks in? :-P

Comment: The "and so on" makes me laugh.  Is there some sort of pattern that is obvious to anyone else?

Comment: @NickAlbrecht No, it is not an example. It is a real situation. The *two* groups are made up of mining workers who work 14 days and rest 14. And the dates are real.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry if i expressed myself wrong. I'm not fluent in english. Anyway, laughing is good for the soul, take it as a thank you for all the times you helped me (yes, I remember your name!) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the base date is `2021-04-09`

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,Grp = 'Group ' + char(65 + (datediff(day,'2021-04-09',date) / 14 ) % 2 )
 From  @dates
```

**Results**

```
date        Grp
2021-04-20  Group A
2021-04-21  Group A
2021-04-22  Group A
2021-04-23  Group B
2021-04-24  Group B
2021-04-25  Group B
```

Comment: There are only two groups: A and B. So it wouldn't be A-B-C-D-E-F, it would be A-B-A-B-A-B-A.